# Using an http_get request to obtain JSON

Tags: php, http, curl

I'm pretty new using third party API's and I need to obtain some data that is formatted in JSON. Documentation [here](https://dashboard.tapjoy.com/dashboard/reporting/api).

```
$url = 'https://api.tapjoy.com/reporting_data.json';
$vars = '?email=myname%40email.com
        &api_key=123456789
        &date=YYYY-MM-DD
       [&page=NUM]
       [&timezone=NUM]';

$parameters = array('email' => 'myemail@me.com'
                    'api_key', => '123456789',
                    '' => '2014-12-22');

$response = http_get($url, $parameters, $info);
print_r($info);
```

I'm not sure if something may be wrong with the way localhost is configured that may be causing this error, but this is what it says in the MAMP error log.

`PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function http_get()`

So, I tried this approach next.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $vars);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        var_dump(@json_decode($data, true));
```

This produces

`NULL`

From my experiences, using `file_get_contents` has always sufficed for me. So, trying `cURL` is a bit foreign to me.

Any ideas?

Comment: The arguments you are using for `json_decode()` are wrong. You probably want `json_decode($data,true)`. Also, remove the `@` operator so you can see any error messages.

Comment: Sorry. Had it switched. I edited my question. It not reads `NULL`

Comment: Could you do var_dump of `$data` without parsing it first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function http_get(),

I believe the `php_http.dll` extension is not enabled.

```
;extension=php_http.dll
```

Remove the `;` colon from above line and should be like as below

```
extension=php_http.dll
```

Finally restart the apache and make sure it enabled using `phpinfo();` function